# In the case of forked frameworks is it correct to tag both the original and the fork?

Tags: discussion, tags

A good example of this is the XNA, and MonoGame. MonoGame doesn't use the XNA framework, it is a re-implementation of the XNA framework. The difference is that all of the code inside MonoGame has been re-written to behave identically to the XNA framework.

[As such it seems every question tagged against Monogame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monogame+xna), is also tagged against XNA.

Is this an appropriate use of tags?

Comment: You linked to a bunch of questions that don't also have the [xna] tag.  There were only 3 last month.  Not so sure why it would be a problem to ask [xna] experts to look at their code.

Comment: I don't know, I see a few [tag:monogame] that aren't [tag:xna]...

Comment: Both XNA and Monogame are pretty unpopular due to the rise of Unity. You're right in that this may not be the most urgent of issues, however it's always seemed strange to me. I've updated the link to contain posts tagged with both to better illustrate my confusion :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with these two frameworks, but I'd imagine that if the upstream has massive adoption and the fork is API-compatible, it's probably beneficial and appropriate to tag the upstream framework, at least for visibility.

If the case that the question being *about the fork becomes immaterial* -- say, because the fork is so similar as to be functionally indistinguishable -- they could be merged or linked as synonyms.

I'm thinking of the example of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) / [IO.js](https://iojs.org/en/), which were API-identical but only those 'in the know' of the schism would even have known IO existed. So I would have cross-tagged IO questions as Node.js in that case. (It was eventually merged back in to Node.js anyway, perhaps a special case.)